# Display only those objects on django admin based on the user profile which is related to user that has logged in currenty

Tags: django, filter, django-admin, multiple-users, django-admin-filters

I want to have an admin where any operator who logs in the admin dashboard can only view their package objects and not see/change package objects added by other operators (from user).

My models:

```
class Package(models.Model):
    operator = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    destination = models.ForeignKey(Destination, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    package_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                related_name='profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=USER_TYPES, default='g')
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
```

My package/admin.py:

```
class PackageAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    icon_name = 'explore'
    autocomplete_fields = ['destination']         

    list_display = ('image_display','package_name',  'featured', 'price', 'discounted_price',
                    'savings', 'fix_departure', 'rating',
                     'date_created',)


    image_display = AdminThumbnail(image_field='thumbnail')
    image_display.short_description = 'Image'
    readonly_fields = ['image_display']

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        abc = super(PackageAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return abc
        else:
            operator = request.user.id
            return abc.filter(operator=operator)
```

I have overridden the get_queryset(self, request) function but it is not working.

My update:

[image]

I see another problem here. Now, although operator cant see/modify another objects but can add the package object on another operators name using email from the dropdown.

The two solutions will be:

1. Only the current user/profile visible in operator field.
2. Although the emails are visible, cant add the package under another operator's email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Package.operator` is a `ForeignKey` to the `UserProfile` model, you need to pass an instance of this model to the filter with `request.user.profile` using the `related_name` from the `OneToOneField`

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    queryset = super(PackageAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return abc
    else:
        operator = request.user.profile
        return queryset.filter(operator=operator)
```

Comment: Hi @Iain, thanks for the solution but I have presented another issue with the image. Can you please solve this??